# "InitializeLifetimeService is not supported on this proxy" when accessing remote object

Tags: c#, sandbox, appdomain, remoting, object-lifetime

I'm trying to execute a method from an object which is loaded from an assembly that is dynamically generated with `CompilerResults.CompiledAssembly`. However, I need this assembly to have restricted permissions because the methods it contains have an unexpected behavior.

I've searched a lot and the Microsoft docs suggest to use the security features provided by .NET Framework 4. [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/misc/how-to-run-partially-trusted-code-in-a-sandbox) is one of the many sources I've read about sandboxing, which uses a different `AppDomain` with restricted permissions. Theoretically, I can create instances from the class within the assembly that is loaded in the restricted `AppDomain` and this instance will be considered a remote object.

To use the new object as a reference, a proxy is created internally when you try to access the object if the class extends the `MarshalByRefObject` class. In my case, the class which extends `MarshalByRefObject` is at the top of the hierarchy.

A simplified version of the code based on the link I've mentioned before is:

```
var permissionSet = ...;
var dllPath = ...;
// Create the AppDomainSetup
var info = new AppDomainSetup
{
    // Set the path to the assembly to load.
    ApplicationBase = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
};
var strongName = assembly.Evidence.GetHostEvidence<StrongName>();
// Create the domain
var sandboxDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("RestrictedDomain", null, info, permissionSet, new StrongName[] { strongName });
var handle = Activator.CreateInstanceFrom(sandboxDomain, dllPath, "MyNamespace.MyClass");
var myLoadedTypeInstance = handle.Unwrap() as MyClass;
```

The code above works, the assembly is loaded in the `AppDomain` (only can do it referencing it's dll location, not it's name). But when I try to use a method from `myLoadedTypeInstance` with two serializable parameters I get an exception. The call is something like `myLoadedTypeInstance.MyMethod(param1, param2)` and the exception is:

**"Method InitializeLifetimeService is not supported on this proxy, this can happen if the method is not marked with OperationContractAttribute or if the interface type is not marked with ServiceContractAttribute."**

Some details:

- I don't know if it matters, but the first parameter is an objects which contains a property of type `TChannel`, created with `ChannelFactory<T>.CreateChannel()`.
- It confuses me that the code fails when initializing lifetime service, but if I use `RemotingServices.GetLifetimeService(myLoadedTypeInstance) as ILease` I can access all the remote object's lifetime info.
- I've also tried to treat it as a remote object explicitly using `Activator.GetObject()` with the URL provided by `RemotingServices.GetObjectUri(myLoadedTypeInstance)`, which is redundant because I end up creating two instances of the object. But it was a desperate move which had the same ending.
- I cannot debug this with VisualStudio as it's running in a separate process.